# Service elasticloadbalancing not available in region eu-central-1

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb, aws-cli

I'm trying to enable Proxy support on my AWS Elastic loadbalancer using the aws cli and get an error when I try to [enable the proxy policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html).

```
Service elasticloadbalancing not available in region eu-central-1
```

My instances are in the Frankfurt region eu-central-1b. The loadbalancer that i created and associated my instances with i'm also is assuming in eu-central-1b.

Any clue how I can enable the proxy-support on my ELB ? Looks like it cannot be done through the AWS management console but has to be done from the command line.

Comment: Could you show the exact CLI command you are using?

Comment: i did aws configure where i set the default region to eu-central-1 and then when i do aws elb describe-load-balancer-policy-types, i get the above error

Comment: Sounds like a locally-generated error, rather than one from an api response... what version of aws cli?

Comment: aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic

Comment: if of any help - on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael - sqlbot - indeed was on an old version of awscli that I got by doing apt-get install awscli

Installed the latest version with pip as below and the upgraded to `aws-cli/1.10.14 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic botocore/1.4.5`

**`pip install --upgrade awscli`**

Set the credentials on ~/.aws/credentials and issued the same command and it worked fine.